How to filter by one category or more in Nextjs 14 app from strapi?
I'm using Next.js 14 and I'm new to Strapi. I'm having trouble finding a proper response, so I'm seeking help here.
Here's how I'm fetching Strapi data on the server page:
const fetchBlogs = async (params) => {
  const reqOptions = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.API_TOKEN}`,
    },
  };
  const request = await fetch(`${config.api}/api/blogs?populate=*&${params}`, reqOptions);
  const response = await request.json();
  return response;
};

const page = async () => {
  const blogs = await fetchBlogs();
};

I have a child component with a list of buttons for each available category, and another child component with a list of blogs.
How can I filter the blogs from the page using the buttons in the child component? How can I change the fetch parameters from here ?  and what exactly do I need to change? I'm confused.
Thanks for your help

I would recommend installing the qs library to help you write your queries.
That way it is much harder to mess up when writing queries.
Here is an example.
Here is my fetch method:
export async function fetchData(url: string, authToken?: string) {

  const headers = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
    },
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, authToken ? headers : {});
    const data = await response.json();
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    throw error; // or return null;
  }
}

And here is where I am using qs to define my query and call my fetch function.
async function loader() {
  const { fetchData } = await import("@/lib/fetch");
  const path = "/api/landing-page";
  const baseUrl = getStrapiURL();

  const query = qs.stringify({
    populate: {
      blocks: {
        on: {
          "layout.hero": {
            populate: {
              image: {
                fields: ["url", "alternativeText", "name"],
              },
              buttonLink:{
                populate: "*",
              },
              topLink: {
                populate: "*",
              }
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });

  const url = new URL(path, baseUrl);
  url.search = query;
  const data = await fetchData(url.href);
  return data;
}

You can learn more about populating and filtering in Strapi from this post I wrote here

Thanks for the interesting article. I understand now how to filter on the Strapi side! But, for example, how would you apply those filters to your fetch loader? How can I connect my category buttons to that? I want to fetch all data, and then filter the data based on the selected category or categories. Also, my category buttons are in a child of a child component, far from the page where I fetch all the data. How would you manage it ? ( Any exemple ? ) Thanks I appreciate
